# Truncated figure with plotly

Tags: python, plotly, scatter3d

I am facing a problem with the Scatter3d from plotly: the figure is always truncated at the bottom:

[image: Truncated scatter 3D]

I create the plot via `plotly.express` this way:

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(BFM_pcaFull, x=0, y=1, z=2, color=3)
```

with `BFM_pcaFull` being the pandas.DataFrame where the data are stored. I tried to create the plot via `plotly.graph_object` instead of `plotly.epxress` but the result is the same.
I tried to tweak the layout parameter via the `update_layout()` method of `fig`:

- Padding
- Auto margin
- Scaling
- scaleratio
- constrain

of course without any change to the graph (which does surprise me and make me think I am doing something wrong, even if apparently the 3D surface seems to follow different rules somewhat).

An issue for the same problem is open on the Github repo of the project but has not been solved so far (https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3785).

Has anybody faced the same problem and found a solution by any chance?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is always a troubling event. It can be corrected by modifying the camera angle. See [here for details](https://plotly.com/python/3d-camera-controls/#changing-the-camera-position-by-setting-the-eye-parameter). Whether the result is satisfactory is another matter. Looking at the improved result, I thought that the 3D view was prioritized at the expense of cutting. `fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0,r=0,t=0,b=0), scene_camera=dict(eye=dict(x=2.0, y=2.0, z=0.75)))`

Comment: Perfect it absolutely solved the problem (thanks for the edit too). I guess you can put your comment as answer so I can up vote it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid missing parts of the graph in a 3D graph, you can change the viewpoint angle. See here for [more information](https://plotly.com/python/3d-camera-controls/#changing-the-camera-position-by-setting-the-eye-parameter). The following code can be used to deal with this problem.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length',
                    y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
                    color='species')
fig.show()
```

[image]

**When the camera viewpoint is changed**

```
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0,r=0,t=0,b=0), scene_camera=dict(eye=dict(x=2.0, y=2.0, z=0.75)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When I encountered a similar problem, it was helpful for me to vary the 'center' parameter as well as the 'eye' parameter (see this [example](https://plotly.com/python/3d-camera-controls/#changing-the-focal-point-by-setting-center) on the plotly website, and the corresponding section of the [api reference](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/scene/)).

The parameters `eye=dict(x=1.3, y=1.3, z=1), center=dict(x=0, y=0, z=-0.2),` worked well for me.
The `eye` parameter determines the position of the camera (eye), relative to the coordinates of the 3D domain (center (0,0,0), and extending to $\pm 1$ in each coordinate I believe).
The `center` parameter determines 'where the eye looks' so a value of -0.2 will shift the plot upwards.

I hope this helps complement the answer above.